# Display Images (Using Volley) in DIalog Box

Tags: android, listview, dialog

i want to show display my image(using voley) and show in display box when item from listview click, here below screenshot apps:

This Listview :

[image: Listview]

and This Dialog Box when Item Click

[image: Dialog Box when item on listview click]

My Question :
how to show images too in dialog box when item from listview clicked?

Here my code :
AbdominalFrgament.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AbdominalFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = AbdominalFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http:.....";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Exercise> exerciseList = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public AbdominalFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), exerciseList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        if(exerciseList.isEmpty()) {
            // Creating volley request obj
            JsonArrayRequest exerciseReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            hidePDialog();

                            exerciseList.clear();

                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
                                    if (obj.getString("tipe").equals("abdominal")) {
                                        exercise.setNama(obj.getString("nama"));
                                        exercise.setGambar1(obj.getString("gambar1"));
                                        exercise.setTipe(obj.getString("tipe"));
                                        exercise.setMainmuscle(obj.getString("mainmuscle"));
                                        exercise.setAlat(obj.getString("alat"));
                                        exercise.setTipe(obj.getString("othermuscle"));
                                        //exercise.setTipe(obj.getString("deskripsi"));
                                        exercise.setRating(obj.getDouble("rating"));
                                        //exercise.setRating(((Number)obj.get("rating")).doubleValue());
                                        // Genre is json array
                               /*JSONArray othermuscleArray = obj.getJSONArray("othermuscle");
                                ArrayList<String> othermuscle = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < othermuscleArray.length(); j++) {
                                    othermuscle.add((String) othermuscleArray.get(j));
                                }
                                exercise.setOthermuscle(othermuscle);*/


                                        //movie.setDescribe(obj.getString("describe"));
                                        //movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                        //        .doubleValue());


                                /*// Genre is json array
                                JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);*/

                                        // adding movie to movies array
                                        exerciseList.add(exercise);
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(exerciseReq);
        }else{
            hidePDialog();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Create custom dialog object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
        // Include dialog.xml file
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog); // layout of your dialog
        // Set dialog title
        dialog.setTitle("Detail");

        // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nama);
        text.setText(exerciseList.get(position).getNama());

        //ImageView text1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gambar1);
       // text1.setText(exerciseList.get(position).getGambar1());

        TextView text3 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.alat);
        text3.setText(exerciseList.get(position).getAlat());

        TextView text4 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mainmuscle);
        text4.setText(exerciseList.get(position).getMainmuscle());
        // similar add statements for other details

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

listrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <!-- Image -->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/gambar1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <!-- Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nama"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gambar1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gambar1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Main Muscle -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainmuscle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nama"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gambar1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Rating -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainmuscle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gambar1"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />

    <!-- alat -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alat"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rating"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gambar1"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />

    <!-- tipe -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tipe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/year" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >


    <!-- Image -->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/gambar1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />


    <!-- Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nama"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gambar1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gambar1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Main Muscle -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainmuscle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nama"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gambar1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Rating -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainmuscle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gambar1"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />

    <!-- alat -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alat"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rating"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gambar1"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />

    <!-- tipe -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tipe"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/year"
        android:layout_below="@id/alat"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How you are resetting NetworkImageView's @+id/gambar1

Comment: hi @Stallion , for resseting or clear cache maybe using appcontrol code, im following this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code reference [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/), the image is set using the following in `CustomListAdapter` class

```
NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
// thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
```

Similar way you have to do in your Dialog also , with the thumbnail URL . This thumbnail you have to pass from `ListView` to `Dialog`

You can probably give different id also for Dialog image view and load that NetworkImageView into the new component in Dialog

Comment: can you give where's a part i must add or change or replace?

Comment: after dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

Comment: You should make necessary changes to achieve this. By passing corresponding parameters.

Comment: hmm its possible to put your code  below `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);` ?
put the code on `AbdominalFragment.java` right?

Answer (score 0):

Change your dialog.xml NetworkImageView id and try again.

Hope following link will help you.

[Try this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-volley-imageloader-networkimageview-example/)

Comment: when im try change id , and app unfortunately stop and given error
`05-06 22:28:46.479 7569-7569/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
05-06 22:28:46.479 7569-7569/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.felix.tirtagympool.AbdominalFragment.onItemClick(AbdominalFragment.java:188)`

Comment: Clear build and try //NetworkImageView text1 = (NetworkImageView ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.changedId);

Comment: and `getPosition`?

Comment: you mean clicked item position?

Comment: `NetworkImageView text1 = (NetworkImageView ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.changedId); `
after that code, i must `setImageUrl` or what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111235/discussion-between-f-x-and-leonemob).